# Passing List between classes

Tags: c#

I am working on a school project. Users can enter Persons objects and store them in List of type Person. It is working fine, expect that when I call the list from another class the list is empty!

```
class SubMenu
{
    CreatePersons cp;
    List<Person> myList = new List<Person>();
    public List<Person> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
    }

    string UserInput= null;
    public void SMenu()
    {

        Boolean flag = true;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(" -------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(" -|---------------------------------------|-");
            Console.WriteLine(" -|- P. Create a Person                  -|-");
            Console.WriteLine(" -|- S. Create a Student                 -|-");
            Console.WriteLine(" -|- T. Create a Teacher                 -|-");
            Console.WriteLine(" -|- A. Create Administrative Staff      -|-");
            Console.WriteLine(" -|- R. Return to Main Menu              -|-");
            Console.WriteLine(" -|---------------------------------------|-");
            Console.WriteLine(" -------------------------------------------");
            Console.Write(" Enter your choice: ");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (UserInput.ToLower())
            {
                case "p": myList.Add(new Person("Johnny"));   //For testing
                          Console.WriteLine(myList.Count);    //For testing .. here count = 1 as it should be.
                          break;
                case "s": Console.WriteLine("Creates and object of type Student.");

                    break;
```

This is the class where the users creates new Persons. I have created one Person for testing. The problem is that when I call the list from another class the list is empty, it should have one peerson in it!
Here is the code from the other class.

```
 class MainMenu
    {
         Boolean flag = true;
         SubMenu sm = new SubMenu();
         public void MMenu()
         {
             while (true)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine();
                 Console.WriteLine("Console Application v1.0 created by");
                 Console.WriteLine();
                 Console.WriteLine(" ---------------------------------------------------");
                 Console.WriteLine(" -|-------------- MENU ---------------------------|-");
                 Console.WriteLine(" -|-----------------------------------------------|-");
                 Console.WriteLine(" -|- 1 -  Create a Person                        -|-");
                 Console.WriteLine(" -|- 2 -  List all the Persons                   -|-");
                 Console.WriteLine(" -|- 3 -  Search for a Person                    -|-");
                 Console.WriteLine(" -|- 4 -  Display the number of Persons          -|-");
                 Console.WriteLine(" -|- 5 -  Exit                                   -|-");
                 Console.WriteLine(" ---------------------------------------------------");
                 Console.Write(" Enter your choice: ");
                 string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
                 Console.WriteLine();

                 int input;
                 if (int.TryParse(UserInput, out input))
                 {
                     switch (input)
                     {
                         case 1:Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                                sm.SMenu();
                                break;
                         case 2:Console.WriteLine("Case 2");  //This should display the one, the current size of the List.
                                int size = sm.MyList.Count;
                                Console.WriteLine("Size :" + size);

                                break;
                         case 3: Console.WriteLine("Case 3");
```

Please take a look at the comments so problem can be easily idetified.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're executing case 1 before case 2 in the MMenu method, right? Otherwise, SMenu hasn't been called, so the list should be empty.

Comment: The order in which you use the menu elements is relevant here, so can you elaborate in which order you are using the menus. Also, is there any code outside the switch statements that gets executed?

Comment: Before I am executing case 2, i am creating a person using case 1 in MMenu and then going to SMenu. But when I return back to MMenu the list is empty.

Comment: Apart from the question of having your List<Person> in you sub menu (look up MVC pattern), learn how to use a debugger, and as it's C#, you'll probably start out with F9 (toggle breakpoint), F10 (step over) and F11 (step into) in Dev Studio.

Comment: Should the list be in the Main Method?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how can you call the `SMenu` wihout set the variable as *static*, so I try to make some change on your code and seem like it *works well*.... if you want to reserve the value you did before, then you need **static**.

I remove the `Person` because I don't know its definition.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        Boolean flag = true;
        //I can only run it after I set it to static
        static SubMenu sm = new SubMenu();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Console Application v1.0 created by");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ---------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(" -|-------------- MENU ---------------------------|-");
                Console.WriteLine(" -|-----------------------------------------------|-");
                Console.WriteLine(" -|- 1 -  Create a Person                        -|-");
                Console.WriteLine(" -|- 2 -  List all the Persons                   -|-");
                Console.WriteLine(" -|- 3 -  Search for a Person                    -|-");
                Console.WriteLine(" -|- 4 -  Display the number of Persons          -|-");
                Console.WriteLine(" -|- 5 -  Exit                                   -|-");
                Console.WriteLine(" ---------------------------------------------------");
                Console.Write(" Enter your choice: ");
                string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                int input;
                if (int.TryParse(UserInput, out input))
                {
                    switch (input)
                    {
                        case 1: Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                            sm.SMenu();
                            break;
                        case 2: Console.WriteLine("Case 2");  //displaying one now if run once
                            int size = sm.MyList.Count;
                            Console.WriteLine("Size :" + size);

                            break;
                        case 3: Console.WriteLine("Case 3");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        class SubMenu
        {
            //CreatePersons cp;
            //replace Person with int
            List<int> myList = new List<int>();
            public List<int> MyList
            {
                get { return myList; }
            }

            string UserInput = null;
            public void SMenu()
            {

                Boolean flag = true;
                //the original while(true) makes me never go out from loop, so I change it.
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -|---------------------------------------|-");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -|- P. Create a Person                  -|-");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -|- S. Create a Student                 -|-");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -|- T. Create a Teacher                 -|-");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -|- A. Create Administrative Staff      -|-");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -|- R. Return to Main Menu              -|-");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -|---------------------------------------|-");
                    Console.WriteLine(" -------------------------------------------");
                    Console.Write(" Enter your choice: ");
                    UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    switch (UserInput.ToLower())
                    {
                        //remove the Person part
                        case "p": myList.Add(1);   //For testing
                            Console.WriteLine(myList.Count);    //Count = 1
                            break;
                        case "s": Console.WriteLine("Creates and object of type Student.");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```